# How to get latest entered record in to the first position in PrimeFaces data table

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

Whenever I add the record into the table it automatically added into the last position.
it should add into the first position, could anyone please help me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMuuS.png)

I want to add latest record into first position in PrimeFaces data table

Comment: whats your code behind the table? you could probably adjust the sort order

Comment: could you please tell me how to do it

Comment: The JSF tag is enough. This question cannot be answered by Java SE experts.

Comment: `list.add(0, item)`, but the exact solution depends on your code.

Comment: Please add a [mcve]